# Why android studio give an error when i add dependency?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I'm building a face detection Android app. When I add dependency inside the `app/build.gradle` it gives me an error. Here is my gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.emojify"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support ', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:10.2.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Error is reported in the following lines:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
```

Comment: what kind of error?

Comment: show us the error log

Comment: Try using implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-rc01' and change the other one to implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1'

Answer (score 0):

Show us a screenshot of your error or format your error to easier reading, just click code button and paste it.
Edit: thank you :)

I think you should use refresh gradle after any changes in gradle.build and maybe you got this error because your build tools sdk is 28.0.3 and you want to use tool from sdk 28.0.0, just change compile sdk to 28.0.0 and click sync gradle on actionbar.

Answer (score 0):

Your buildToolVersion is greater than your design and appcompat-v7.
Try to change,

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.3' //or greater than 28.0.3  
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.3' //or greater than 28.0.3
```

connect to the internet and then build your project. Problem will be solved.